# How can I fetch attributes from User model using UserProfile's OneToOneField relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'd love to write a form where a user can change their data. So I have a User model and a UserProfile extension model, the last one looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    info = models.TextField('информация')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('user_profile', args=[str(self.user.username)])
```

How to generate a form where my user attribute would have all its parameters like `username`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name` to be changed? So I could do something like this in the template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h2>{{ title }}</h2>

<div class="row">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'profile_edit' user.username %}" class="col s12">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                {{ form.user.username }}
                {{ form.user.username.label_tag }}
                {% if form.user.username.errors %}
                <span class="helper-text">{{ form.user.username.errors }}</span>
                {% else %}
                <span class="helper-text">{{ form.user.username.help_text }}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                {{ form.user.email }}
                {{ form.user.email.label_tag }}
                {% if form.user.email.errors %}
                <span class="helper-text">{{ form.user.email.errors }}</span>
                {% else %}
                <span class="helper-text">{{ form.user.email.help_text }}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                {{ form.user.first_name }}
                {{ form.user.first_name.label_tag }}
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                {{ form.user.last_name }}
                {{ form.user.last_name.label_tag }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                {{ form.info }}
                {{ form.info.label_tag }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue" type="submit" name="action">Изменить</button>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-flat" href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Сменить пароль</a>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

And finally, this is my view, obviously incorrect:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from datetime import datetime

from .models import *

class UserEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, generic.UpdateView): # still does not work
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'accounts/user_form.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=self.request.user)

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user == self.get_object().user

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        user = User.objects.get_by_natural_key(form.cleaned_data['user'])
        user.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        user.first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        user.userprofile.info = form.cleaned_data.get('info')
        user.save()
        return response

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Редактировать профиль'
        context['year'] = datetime.now().year
        return context
```

All of this does nothing but produces status 200 response.

Comment: You have to create your custom form, `cleaned_data.get('first_name')`, `cleaned_data.get('last_name') ` are always empty because these not present in the form. Here can be used [inline-formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Comment: @NKSM, Do you mean creating a form in `forms.py` and then refer to it in `form_class` of `UserEditView` with `UserProfile` object? And in that view create an inline-formset and work with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of solutions:

1. Create 2 `forms`: `UserForm` and `UserProfileForm`.

```py
profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
if profile_form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
   profile_form.save()
   user_form.save()

    ....
```

2. Without 2 `forms`:

Write your own method inside `form_valid` and pass variables from `request.POST` to your profile

Also, you may check this [user profile in drf](https://dev.to/a1k89/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializer-515f)